# Ways to find a confidence interval for robust and quantile regressions

Tags: r, regression, robust, quantile-regression

I'm trying to compare a few regression models for my data. For linear regression everything is quite understandable, but robust and quantile regressions are not so obvious. I could not find almost anything about calculating confidence interval for these regression models unless I looked for something wrong.

This is my code in R

```
# Robust linear modeling
library(MASS)
library(robustbase)
library(robust)
set.seed(343); 
x <- rnorm(1000)
y <- x + 2*rnorm(1000)

lm1<-lm(y~x); rlm1<-rlm(y~x); rlm2 <- lmRob(y~x); rlm3 <- lmrob(y~x)
cbind(summary(lm1)$coeff,  confint(lm1)) 
cbind(summary(rlm1)$coeff, confint(rlm1))
cbind(summary(rlm2)$coeff, confint(rlm2))
cbind(summary(rlm3)$coeff, confint(rlm3))
```

This code produces the following result:

```
> cbind(summary(lm1)$coeff,  confint(lm1))
                   Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)      2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) -0.06973191 0.06408983 -1.088034 2.768429e-01 -0.1954982 0.05603438
x            0.97647196 0.06619635 14.751145 1.071805e-44  0.8465720 1.10637196
> cbind(summary(rlm1)$coeff, confint(rlm1))
                  Value Std. Error    t value 2.5 % 97.5 %
(Intercept) -0.06131788 0.06714405 -0.9132288    NA     NA
x            0.96016596 0.06935096 13.8450275    NA     NA
> cbind(summary(rlm2)$coeff, confint(rlm2))
    Error in UseMethod("vcov") : 
      no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "lmRob"
> cbind(summary(rlm3)$coeff, confint(rlm3))
              Estimate Std. Error    t value     Pr(>|t|)      2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept) -0.0568964 0.06608987 -0.8608945 3.895029e-01 -0.1865874 0.07279464
x            0.9612520 0.06821558 14.0913850 2.921913e-41  0.8273896 1.09511448
```

It's easy to spot that linear model works OK and only one robust regression gives a sensible result. Another observation is that lmrob(), which produces some actual confidence interval, calculates it in the same manner as lm(), with using 1.96 as the student coefficient.

Is it a correct way to produce a confidence interval for the robust regression model? May the same method be used for the quantile regression model?

Comment: "and only one robust regression gives a sensible result." A better way to say that is that only one of the robust functions was designed to work with the 'confint()' interval..."Is it a correct way to produce a confidence interval for the robust regression model?" yes. "May the same method be used for the quantile regression model?' just use summary on an object produced by 'rq' (quantreg).

Comment: Why other functions, which give very similar results don't work with confint()? Is it just a bug or I'm going in wrong direction?

Comment: This is the code for rq
rqm1 <- rq(y~x)
summary(rqm1, se = "nid")
confint(rqm1)
confint() doesn't work here either: no applicable method for 'vcov' applied to an object of class "rq"
So I need to take Value and Std.Error columns and construct my own confidence intervals since it's not implemented in the package? If it's so simple, why there is no any implementation of it anywhere and just books or quite long articles about confidence intervals for robust and quantile regressions? That's I believe it's not so easy.

Comment: not necessarily: R is not made by a centralized organization so different functions (from different packages) can well not be compatible with one another.